# Get same column twice with different conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I would like to retrive same columns twice but with different conditions.

my Query is like this but the following Query retrives two different columns. But I want to get the same column twice, How can I achieve this?

```
Select name from tbCustomer where ID in (select ID from tbOldCustomer where oldID= 1)
Select name from tbCustomer where ID in (select ID from tbOldCustomer where oldID= 2)
```

**tbCustomer** has two columns:
**ID**   **name**
1   aaa
2     bbb
3     ccc
4     ddd

**tbOldCustomer** has two columns:

**ID**  **oldID**
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    2
4    1

would like to get name where oldID in (1, 2) and the output should be the follwing:

**name**    **name1**
bbb       aaa
ccc       ddd
ddd

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. All as formatted text, not images.

Comment: @jarlh: attached image.

Comment: You must be kidding... I clearly wrote "_as formatted text, not images_", and you still attached an image. Hilarious.

Comment: The column names in your queries don't match the ones in the image.

Comment: @jarlh: updated!

Answer (score 1):

use exists

```
select t1.name 
from tbCustomer t1 
exists( select 1 from  tbOldCustomer t2  where  t1.id = t2.id
                                       and t2.oldid in (1,2)
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve that by using simply `JOIN`

```
Select name 
from tbCustomer tc 
inner join tbOldCustomer toc On toc.id = tc.id
where toc.oldID IN (1,2)
```

Comment: your Query retrive only one Column. But I want to retrive "name"-coulmn twice with different values.

Comment: @darma: that is totally unclear from your question. You need to add sample data and the expected result as jarlh suggested

Comment: @Susang : Updated!

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `conditional aggregation` with `case when expression`

```
select max(case when oldID= 1 then name end) as name1,
       max(case when oldID= 2 then name end) as name2
from tbCustomer join tbOldCustomer on ID=oldID where oldid in (1,2)
group by oldid
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to try

```
Select tc.name, toc.name from tbCustomer tc inner join 
tbOldCustomer toc On toc.id = c.id where toc.oldID IN (1,2)
```

Comment: The problem here is: there is no "name" column in tbOldCustomer. so giving me error at toc.name

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
Select name from tbCustomer where ID in (select ID from tbOldCustomer where oldID IN(1,2))
```

OR

```
Select A.name from tbCustomer A
INNER JOIN tbOldCustomer  B
ON A.id = B.Id
AND B.OldId In (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  name 
FROM tbCustomer tb1 
JOIN (SELECT ID FROM tbOldCustomer WHERE oldID = 1 OR oldID= 2) tb2
     ON tb1.ID = tb2.ID
WHERE tb1.ID IN (SELCT ID from tbOldCustomer where oldID in (1, 2))
```